# Bezier curve in Java with Points

Tags: java, graphics, drawing, bezier

I'm trying to make a simple program that will draw a Curve through randomly generated points.But something goes wrong and the compiler gives an error.I'm just starting to learn java and this is one of the first tasks. I hope you can point out my mistakes. Here is the code

```
public class Framey {

private static int fact(int n) {
    int fact = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n;i++) {
        fact *= i;
    }
    return fact;
}

private static double bernstein(float t,int n,int i) {
    return (fact(n)/(fact(i)*fact(n-i)))*Math.pow(1-t, n-i)*Math.pow(t, i);
}


private JFrame frame;



/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Framey window = new Framey();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Framey() {
    initialize();

}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    panel.setBounds(23, 35, 250, 200);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);


    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
    spinner.setBounds(291, 113, 30, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(spinner);

    JLabel warning = new JLabel("Value cannot be larger than 8!");
    warning.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 9));
    warning.setBounds(283, 144, 141, 53);
    frame.getContentPane().add(warning);
    warning.setVisible(false);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int pointCount;

            pointCount = (int) spinner.getValue();
            if (pointCount>8) {
                warning.setVisible(true);
            }else {warning.setVisible(false);}




            Point[] points = getPoints(pointCount); 

             drawScene(points);
        }
        private  Point[] getPoints(int pointCount) {
            Random val = new Random();
            Point[] points = new Point[pointCount];
            for(int i=0;i<pointCount;i++) {
                points[i].x = val.nextInt(panel.getWidth());
                points[i].y =val.nextInt(panel.getHeight());
            }
            return points;
        }
        private void drawScene(Point[] points) {
            int pWidth = panel.getWidth();
            int pHeight = panel.getHeight();
            Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
            int pointCount = points.length;
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0,0, pWidth, pHeight);

            if(pointCount>1) {
                float t = 0;
                while( t<=1) {
                    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                    besierCurve(t, points);
                    t+=0.001;
                }
            }
        };


        private void besierCurve(float t , Point[] points) {

            Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
            int pointCount = points.length; 
            double bPoly[] = new double[pointCount];
            for(int i =0;i<pointCount;i++) {
                bPoly[i] = bernstein(t,pointCount-1,i+1);
            }

            double sumX = 0;
            double sumY = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<pointCount;i++) {
                sumX += bPoly[i] * points[i].x;
                sumY += bPoly[i] * points[i].y;
            }

            int x , y;
            x=(int) Math.round(sumX);
            y=(int) Math.round(sumY);
            g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);

        }






    });
```

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at bezjeLiikne.Framey$2.getPoints(Framey.java:106) at bezjeLiikne.Framey$2.actionPerformed(Framey.java:98)

Comment: What is the error from the compiler and what line does it indicate in your source code (mark it)? Without that information your question is incomplete and will likely be closed.

Comment: Show us the error pls

Comment: Read up on what an SSCCE is. Also since you're new here, for good measure read the Tour in the circled question mark menu.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at bezjeLiikne.Framey$2.getPoints(Framey.java:106)
 at bezjeLiikne.Framey$2.actionPerformed(Framey.java:98)
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)

further derivative exceptions go on

Comment: A note on your approach: _don't work with factorials_ because they are entirely irrelevant when what you need is binomial coefficients, We already know a much easier way to compute those: Pascal's Triangle. Predefine (1,2,1) and  (1,3,3,1) for use with quadratic and cubic Beziers, and now you have all the information needed to generate the coefficients for higher order curves, if you need those (which is almost never the case).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `getPoints` method. Creating an array of Points doesn't create any points, it just creates the space where you can store references to Points. But these references are all `null` initially, and that's why you're getting that `NullPointerException`.

So you need to create `Point` instances before trying to assign the `x` and `y` fields.

Change:

```
points[i].x = val.nextInt(panel.getWidth());
points[i].y =val.nextInt(panel.getHeight());
```

To:

```
points[i] = new Point(val.nextInt(panel.getWidth()), val.nextInt(panel.getHeight());
```

Comment: This worked thanks, but now another problem has arisen related to the fact that the curve moves in the wrong direction, always in the direction of the coordinate origin. Which approach would be more appropriate here?

Comment: start at `(1-t)^(n-i) * t^i`, not at `(1-t)^i * t^(n-i)` (and also, don't use factorials, you don't need them. In fact, if you code is for cubic curves, the coefficients are fixed, you don't even need that `bernstein` method)